# My jQuery gallery is too slow and I can't find the reason why

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, jquery-animate, gallery

I am making a jQuery gallery, but for some reason every animation function takes so long to execute.
There is a simple HTML page with a table that is filled with PHP( which I imagine has nothing to do with the problem since it is preloaded by the server) and a script tag beneath that calls the effect. I haven't even finished it because it started "jumping" from the beggining...the fade is not smooth at all...

The image inside gallery is about 40 KB size
That is all I'm calling and it is already slow...

I am making a jQuery gallery, but for some reason every animation function takes so long to execute.
There is a simple HTML page with a table that is filled with PHP( which I imagine has nothing to do with the problem since it is preloaded by the server) and a script tag beneath that calls the effect. I haven't even finished it because it started "jumping" from the beggining...the fade is not smooth at all...

The image inside gallery is about 40 KB size
That is all I'm calling and it is already slow...

```
<script> 
    $("#gallery_base").hide();
    $("#gallery").hide();
    $(".item_par_pic").click(function () {
        $("#gallery_base").fadeTo(550, 0.8);
        $("#gallery").fadeTo(550, 1);
    }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("#gallery").fadeTo(550, 1)
```

[.fadeTo()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/) takes a value between ZERO (clear) and ONE (opaque). A value of 550 makes no sense.

Comment: That is the speed attribute. The second one is the opacity.